# How to use posix getline to read arbitrarily long block of text

Tags: c, posix

I want to read an arbitrary long string from a file. I want to read it linewise, but obtain a pointer to a string containing the full input. Evidently I will want to implement a certain configurable limit for the total length (which could be checked each time before the next line is read).
I wanted to use the POSIX functions and began to implement something simple based on `getline()`, starting with http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html .
Can I use `getline` to achieve this, for example by executing it in a `while`-loop and passing a pointer to the end of the previously read string? How would I free the dynamically allocated memory?

The following code works but reads only the lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  ssize_t bytes_read;
  size_t nbytes = 100;
  char *my_string;
  FILE *input;

  input = fopen("tmp.txt", "r");

  my_string = (char *)malloc(nbytes+1);

  while((bytes_read=getline(&my_string, &nbytes, input))>=0){
        printf("read: %ld bytes", bytes_read);
        printf("length of string: %ld bytes", strlen(my_string)-1);
        puts(my_string);
  }

  free(my_string);

  fclose(input);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you by showing your code.

Comment: Tons of possible solutions. For example, you can use `fgets` in a loop and check the last character, and use `realloc` throughout.

Comment: Well, yes, but I don't intend to reinvent the wheel. It appears to be a standard task for which there should be code-snippets available somewhere.

Comment: 1) investigate the size of the file 2) malloc 3) fread

Comment: Of course, the purpose is not to simply slurp the whole file. I want to read it line wise, because I want to decide whether to continue reading or not after each individual read. I.e. there will be a operation on each line in the loop.

Comment: If you want (quite reasonably) to restrict yourself to POSIX functions, then why are you considering `getline()`?  It's a GNU extension function.

Comment: @JohnBollinger CONFORMING TO Both getline() and getdelim() were originally GNU extensions.  They were standardized in POSIX.1-2008. So you're incorrect there.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation ([Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)):

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

"If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed."

You are relieved of the responsibility to allocate the buffer for a single line.

To read all lines, allocate an array of pointers to characters.

```
char* lines[200];
```

or

```
int MAX_LINES = 10000;
char** lines;
lines = malloc(MAX_LINES * sizeof(char*));
int i = 0;
long totalsize = 0; 
long bytesread;

do {
    lines[i] = NULL;
    bytesread = getline(&lines[i], (size_t) 0 , yourFileHandle);
    totalsize += bytesread;
    ++i;
} while (bytesread > 0);

// Allocate buffer of size totalsize
// Copy the lines into it
// Deallocate all lines pointers
```

Code not compiled nor tested. Just gave you the idea.

Comment: But how would I obtain a long string which contains all read lines?

Comment: The problem I have here is that I don't get a single string. The reason why I need this is that I need to feed the string to a library function and it would not accept the array.

Comment: See my last commented lines on how you can concatenate the read lines into a single one. Moreover, instead of reading tge file one line at a time, you can open it in binary mode, determine its size, allocate a buffer of that size and read it all in one shot. Forget getline.

Comment: Sorry! Your last comment was mentioned above also, but is not an option, because I intend to continue reading the whole file only if the lines pass some tests.

Comment: Again I provided a solution to read the lines and concatenate them once read. Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: I think your proposal with the commented block would fulfill my requirements. Only the fact that I need to allocate new memory and copy all strings would produce some overhead which seems unnecessary. Also the behavior of getline seems such that the strings can contain null characters. I.e., I would need to store the different values of bytesread in order to copy the complete strings later, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can read data from a file into a dynamically-sized buffer via a function similar to GNU `getline()`, with some buffer-management thrown in.  Something like this, for example:

```
/*
 * Reads up to the specified number of chars from the specified stream,
 * appending them to the end of the data in the specified buffer.
 * Allocates a new buffer if the given one is NULL, an reallocates the
 * buffer if more space is needed than its current capacity.  The buffer
 * is ensured null-terminated.  Returns the number of new chars actually
 * read, excluding the terminator, or -1 on failure to read any data.
 *
 * buffer: a pointer to the location where the address of the target buffer
 *         is stored; NULL if no buffer has yet been allocated; the
 *         caller is repsonsible for freeing the pointed-to buffer.
 * buf_cap: a pointer to the capacity of the allocated buffer; updated at
 *         need.  The value initially stored here is ignored when *buffer
 *         is NULL.
 * buf_len: a pointer to the number of valid chars currently in the buffer,
 *         not including any null terminator; new data will be stored
 *         starting at the next position.  The pointed-to value is updated
 *         when chars are successfully read.
 * num_chars: the number of characters requested to be read; the actual
 *         number read may be fewer.
 * stream: the stream from which to read.
 */
ssize_t extend_line(char **buffer, size_t *buf_cap, size_t *buf_len,
        size_t num_chars, FILE *stream) {
    size_t n_read;

    if (!*buffer) { /* No buffer allocated yet */
        if (! (*buffer = malloc(num_chars + 1))) {
            /* allocation failure */
            return -1;
        }
        *buf_cap = num_chars;
        *buf_len = 0;
    } else if (*buf_len > *buf_cap) {
        /* invalid arguments */
        return -1;
    } else if (*buf_cap - *buf_len <= num_chars) {
        /* extend the buffer */
        size_t needed_cap = *buf_len + num_chars + 1;
        char *temp = realloc(*buffer, needed_cap);

        if (temp) {
            *buffer = temp;
            *buf_cap = needed_cap;
        } else {
            /* reallocation failure */
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /* There is now enough space for at least num_chars additional chars */
    n_read = fread(*buffer + *buf_len, 1, num_chars, stream);
    if (n_read) {
        /* update the data length and ensure null termination */
        *buf_len += n_read;
        (*buffer)[*buf_len] = '\0';
        return n_read;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Fixed-size read requests such as implemented there are comparatively easy, but you could use a similar approach to read to end of line, as `getline()` does.  In that case you might need to `realloc()` more than once per call, but I would advise you then to expand the buffer in chunks, rather than one byte at a time.